# Remove 1 character from both sides of a recurring substring where one digit changes in each occurrence

Tags: r, stringr

I need to remove apostrophes from both sides of a sub-string. The substring occurs numerous times within a starting string, and one digit changes within the substring for each occurrence.

```
starting_string = "{'color':'Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]','color':'Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]','color':'Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2]'}"

substring = Highcharts.getOptions().colors[i]

desired_string = "{'color':Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0],'color':Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1],'color':Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2]}"
```

Above, in 'substring', 'i' represents the digit that changes in each occurrence of the substring.

The number of times 'substring' occurs in 'starting_string' will vary.  This example is simplified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
gsub("'(Highcharts\\.getOptions\\(\\)\\.colors\\[[0-9]+\\])'",
     "\\1", starting_string)
# [1] "{'color':Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0],'color':Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1],'color':Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2]}"
```

Explanation of the regex:

- the parens `(Hig...)` define a group that we'll reference later using `\\1`;
- the enveloping `'` are the literal single quotes; note that these are *outside* the paren-group, as we will want to drop them once we find them;
- I took the liberty of inferring that `i` means "any number", so I replaced it with `[0-9]+` which means "one or more digit".
- many characters have special meaning in regex, so they are backslash-escaped; here, they are `(`, `)`, `[`, `]`, and `.`. For the record, I might have been able to omit all of the backslashes and used instead `fixed=TRUE`, *except* that we want to be able to match on arbitrary numbers in `[i]`.

Comment: And I should be slapping my hands away, and per instructions won't say tha..s, but explanations always help with `regex`.